# Как посчитать количество одинаковых значений в столбце?

Tags: bash, сортировка

Подскажите, как посчитать количество одинаковых значений в столбце так, чтобы в итоге получился список строк в том же порядке и без удаленных дубликатов?

`sort file | uniq -c` меняет порядок строк и удаляет дубликаты. Попробовал пронумеровать строки `cat` или `nl -ba file` , чтобы потом можно было восстановить порядок, но все равно не понимаю как посчитать повторяющиеся строки без изменения первоначального порядка строк в столбце.

Пробую вот так:

```bash
nl -ba col4.tmp > file1.tmp
sort -k2 file2.tmp | uniq -f2 -c > file3.tmp
```

но все равно дубли удаляются

– Нужно из вот такого:

```txt
текст1 
текст2 

текст1

текст1
текст2
текст3
```

– Сделать вот такое:

```txt
текст1;3
текст2;2
;2
текст1;3
;2
текст1;3
текст2;2
текст3;1
```

Пустые строки нельзя удалять, их нужно тоже посчитать.

Comment: заголовок вопроса и метки у вас противоречат содержанию: в заголовки и в метках речь о программе bash, а в вопросе уже совершенно про другие программы: nl, sort, uniq, cat (программа bash к этим программам не имеет никакого отношения).

Comment: Ну так вы на полпути остановились. `sort | uniq -c` вам даёт *набор* вида ключ-значение (ну только в противоположном порядке), теперь вам надо сопоставить Это всё с исходным файлом. Если хочется сделать эффективно, то тут надо либо над `sed` покумекать, либо уже на `awk` идти. Если же `bash` хочется, то там вроде была имплементация стркутуры данных *HASH* (*набор*).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант попробовать создать функцию:

```
sorter() {
#Создаем временный файл, который в дальнейшем будем обрабатывать
    cat "${1}" > "${1}".tmp
#Запускаем цикл, считывая две переменные count и string
    while IFS='~' read count row; do
#Меняем значение в temp файле, на нужные
        sed -i "/^${row}$/s/$/;${count}/" "${1}".tmp
#Передаем в цикл отсортированный список уникальных записей, в данном случае разделитель ~
#При необходимости разделитель меняется в двух местах IFS='~' и \1~
    done< <(sort "${1}"  | uniq -c | sed -r 's/^[ \t]+([0-9]+)[ \t]+/\1~/')
}
```

И запускаем ее передавая параметр файл. После запуска в том же каталоге будет создаваться еще один файл, с дополнительным расширением .tmp, в нем и будут строки отсортированные по примеру.

```
sorter ./file1.txt
cat ./file1.txt.tmp
```

Comment: *Useless use of cat* ну и т.д...

Comment: @0andriy почему бесполезное? или это про то, что можно на `cp` заменить?

Comment: `sed -e "$(sort $1 | uniq -c | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*\([[:digit:]]\+\) \(.*\)/s,^\2$,\2;\1,;/')" $1`

Comment: Ну и конечно вышеприведенное решение не лишено недостатков, всё же надо понимать, что shell не для этого.